# Got Pi5 w PiOS Bookworm, Want ROS 2 Humble Desktop Docker with Nav2 and more

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, raspberry-pi, docker, cv-bridge

I have a working ROS 2 Humble robot (Raspberry Pi4 based GoPiGo3 robot running Ubuntu 22.04) that runs nav2 async mapping, localization, and navigation at close to 100% load.

I just acquired a Raspberry Pi5 and the robot power supply cannot support swapping the Pi5 in for the Pi4, so I would like to try offloading nav2 nodes to the Pi5 running Humble in Docker.

I followed the ROS 2 Docker setup guide, but the ROS 2 Humble Desktop Docker container does not appear to have tf-transformations or Nav2 in the container.

Eventually, I will need the ros-perception/vision_opencv cv_bridge package also.

How can I create a ROS 2 Humble environment with all the packages I need installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a dockerfile to build your own docker image starting from the ROS 2 Humble container. Such a dockerfile could look something like this:

```
from osrf/ros:humble-desktop

# Install Nav2 packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   ros-$ROS_DISTRO-navigation2 \
   ros-$ROS_DISTRO-nav2-bringup \
   ros-$ROS_DISTRO-robot-localization \
   ros-$ROS_DISTRO-slam-toolbox
```

Build the container using the `docker build` command, though you'll need to look up all the extra options you may want.